# PHP mailer multiple addresses

Tags: php, phpmailer

I have a problem with my php mailer function when I use more than one address. Here is the code that I use:

```
$message = $_POST['txtMesssage'];
 $mail->SetFrom('my@mydomain.com');
 $mail->AddCC('my@mydomain.com');
 $mail->AddReplyTo("my@mydomain.com");
 $mail->Subject    = $_POST['txtSubject'];
 $mail->Body = $message;
  $mail->IsHTML(true);
 $address = $_POST['txtTO'];
$mail->AddAddress($address);
```

where text TO is like:

> a.b@yourdomain.com,b.b@yourdomain.com,c.b@yourdomain.com,
>   d.b@yourdomain.com,
>   e.b@yourdomain.com,f.b@yourdomain.com,g.b@yourdomain.com

Any idea, how I can make it work? Thanks

EDIT:

That works for me:

```
$addresses = explode(',', $_POST['txtTO']);
    foreach ($addresses as $address) {
    $mail->AddAddress($address);
    }
```

Thanks!

Comment: Try removing all the spaces after the comma. You got one as far as I can see.

Comment: You need to add the array of emails in a `foreach` loop. Like so: `foreach($emails as $email) { $mail->AddAddress($email); }`

Comment: Just FYI, this script is easy to exploit as a spam gateway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using array concepts, get all the form value i mean the to address in an array iterate and send it. This is like sending separate mail to recipients automated by a for loop .

```
 $Address = array(); 
    $Address[] = $_POST['txtTO']; 
    foreach($Address AS $Add=>$ToEmail){ 
    mail($ToEmail, $Subject, $Message, $mailheaders);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$addresses = explode(',', $_POST['txtTO'];);
foreach ($addresses as $address) {
$mail->AddAddress($address);
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! It Works!


$addresses = explode(',', $_POST['txtTO']);

Comment: Please explain what is wrong with OP's code and why this solves the problem *by editing your answer.*